# Load custom image from file system in scikit-image

Tags: python, image, filesystems, threshold, scikit-image

I am new to Python and I am trying to do the tutorial, shown on the official page. My goal is, to analyze a picture I've created, using the Local Otsu Threshold method.

The code with an example picture works fine but I want to read a custom image, which is stored in the same directory, as the `*.py`-file.

This is the code:

```
from skimage import data
from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu, rank
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 9
img = img_as_ubyte(data.page())

radius = 15
selem = disk(radius)

local_otsu = rank.otsu(img, selem)
threshold_global_otsu = threshold_otsu(img)
global_otsu = img >= threshold_global_otsu

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 5), sharex=True, sharey=True,
                       subplot_kw={'adjustable': 'box-forced'})
ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3 = ax.ravel()

fig.colorbar(ax0.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray),
             ax=ax0, orientation='horizontal')
ax0.set_title('Original')
ax0.axis('off')

fig.colorbar(ax1.imshow(local_otsu, cmap=plt.cm.gray),
             ax=ax1, orientation='horizontal')
ax1.set_title('Local Otsu (radius=%d)' % radius)
ax1.axis('off')

ax2.imshow(img >= local_otsu, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax2.set_title('Original >= Local Otsu' % threshold_global_otsu)
ax2.axis('off')

ax3.imshow(global_otsu, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax3.set_title('Global Otsu (threshold = %d)' % threshold_global_otsu)
ax3.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

More specifically I want to load my image `example.jpg` instead of

```
img = img_as_ubyte(data.page())
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [io.imread](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread) function

```py
img = io.imread('/path/to/example.jpg')
```

Answer (score 9):

Load image using skimage library.

If not installed: pip install -U scikit-image

Load image:

```
    from skimage import io
    img = io.imread('file_path')
```